# Pass javascript object to winrt component written in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-runtime

I have created a WinRT component in C# which accepts a collection as a parameter.

```
namespace MyNamespace {
  public sealed class MyClass {
    public MyFunction(IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> properties) {
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to use this component in javascript as follows:

```
var x = new MyNamespace.MyClass();
x.MyFunction({'aaa': 'bbbb'});
```

I am not sure why this is not working. Any Ideas?

Comment: My first thought is possibly that `{'aaa': 'bbbb'} != IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string>`

Comment: I tried IDictionary Instead of IReadOnlyDictionary and it doesn't work. I also tried to see what the definition looks like after the compilation of component takes place and the method signature looks like Windows.Foundation.Collections.IMap<string, string> but I don't know how to create such an object in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [this is your answer](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/0cc45e2e-144b-49f8-af1a-7bfb73a368f5).

```
var ps = new Windows.Foundation.Collections.PropertySet();
ps['aaa'] = "bbb";

var x = new MyNamespace.MyClass();
x.MyFunction(ps);
```

*"Your WinRT component will need to expose (or reuse) a concrete class implementing the specific instantiation of IMap that you need..."*

Comment: I think this works but it is quite inconvenient since I just have to re-implement all the dictionary methods again :( (marked your answer as answer since it at least works)

Comment: Well you might be able to overload the methods to accept the javascript compatable object, reformat it, then pass it to the original method.